# Why HAVING clause in PROC SQL doesn't turn blue?

Tags: sas, having, proc, clause

I am creating an output that has duplicate values, but the HAVING clause doesn't turn 'blue'. [image]

The code does what it is supposed to do though.
Could anybody explain why HAVING is not 'blue' and if this is a problem?

Comment: Which GUI tool are you using?

Comment: I am using the GUI on SAS 9.3

Comment: As long as it works it's fine.  Syntax highlighting in DM isn't perfect.  EG highlights that correctly.

Comment: It works fine. I crossed checked the output I am getting with proc sort dupout and getting identical results. Thank you for clarification!

Comment: I'm not sure who is downvoting this but if you are please leave a comment. SAS is a complex product, your insight might be helpfull.

Comment: I am also puzzled by downvotes and it would be helpful if those could be explained here.

Comment: If you *really* want it blue, you can add it as a User Defined Keyword.  Open an enhanced editor window in the GUI.  Go to Tools->Options->Enhanced Editor.  On the general tab, click User Defined Keywords.  Add the word 'having'.  It should now show up blue.

Comment: Thanks Rob. This is a good info to keep in mind too!

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @RobPenridge :)

Comment: @Joe I already liked the existing answer and didn't want to detract =)

Comment: Nothing wrong with 2 answers :)  Comments may eventually be deleted, so it's a good idea to put useful stuff like that in an answer when it actually does answer the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DM has its quirks, and this looks like one of them.  Enterprise Guide highlights it correctly.  As long as it works, don't worry about highlighting - if it doesn't work of course it can be an indication of a problem, but in this case it's fine.

Comment: Thank you! I also checked this in EG and it does look highlighted. This is good to know :)